# Solve this inequality.

Tags: inequality

Please, check this inequality :

I want to find $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sqrt {x-\frac{1}{8}}>x$.

Can i $(x-\frac{1}{8})^2>x^2$ is what's wrong ?

Comment: $(\sqrt{y})^2=y$

Comment: @Muthomoephic Yes but with inequalities you must be  cautious. For example $-0.3>-1$ but $(-0.3)^2<(-1)^2$. In this case $x>1/8$ so that the inequality remains uncharged after square.

Comment: The correct term is inequality and not inequation.

Comment: @Chungwow Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You can't have $x<\frac18$, because then $\sqrt{x-\frac18}$ would make no sense. Otherwise, since both numbers $x$ and $\sqrt{x-\frac18}$ are greater than or equal to $0$,$$x<\sqrt{x-\frac18}\iff x^2<\sqrt{x-\frac18}^2=x-\frac18.$$Solve this inequality, keeping in mind that $x\geqslant\frac18$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality corresponds to the following system

- $\sqrt {x-\frac{1}{8}}>x$
- $x-\frac{1}{8}\ge 0$

from the second we obtain $x \ge \frac 18>0$ and therefore we can square both sides to obtain

$$\left(\sqrt {x-\frac{1}{8}}\right)^2>x^2 \iff x-\frac{1}{8}>x^2$$

indeed for $A,B\ge 0$ we have

$$A>B \iff A^2>B^2$$

A completely different case is

$$\sqrt {x+\frac{1}{8}}>x$$

indeed here we need to consider separately $2$ cases

- $-\frac18\le x\le 0 \implies$ the inequality is always true since RHS is negative
- $x>0$ we can square both sides to obtain $x+\frac18 >x^2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

On the domaine defined by $A\ge 0$,
$$\sqrt{A}>B\iff(B<0)\;\text{ OR }\;\bigl(B\ge 0\;\text{ and }A>B^2\bigr)$$